# Can't scale down database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have created a Cosmos DB Database and set throughput to be provisioned at the database level.

When the number of containers exceeds 4 the throughput starts automatically increasing by 100 RU/s for every new container (as expected).

The problem is that if I delete some containers I can't seem to scale the RU/s back down, e.g, if I have 10 containers the throughput goes to 1000 RU/s but if I delete 5 of these containers I can't scale back down to 500 RU/s.

Is this by design or is there some way I can scale back down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once CosmosDB created enough physical partitions to match your load and requirements, it won't delete them. From what I've observed it will only scale out the physical partitions when it has enough RUs and documents but not back in when these documents aren't there anymore. This is for the collection level RU provisioning, but database level one also works quire similar unless you provision collection specific throughput which is dedicated to the collection itself.

Comment: Thanks Nick, do you know if there's any reference to this in the documentation?

Comment: There is no direct link but it can be inferred by the fact that once a physical partition is created, it won't be deleted and each physical partition has a minimum amount of RUs that can be allocated it to it.